# Single quote _'_ embedded in field prevents successful SQL query

Tags: sql, c, ms-access

I use a commercial data base that is delivered with fields such as:

```
Super Crew 5 1/2' Bed 4WD  // where single quote (') symbolizes feet
```

When this field is required to be used in an SQL query, it expands out similar to this excerpt:

```
...WHERE TitleIndex.Title='Super Crew 5 1/2' Bed 4WD'
```

Resulting in an error message *query expression missing operator*. The portion of the intended string literal >>> Bed 4WD'<<< is not understood because of the single quote preceding it.

***Note***:  If I manually edit the database field to replace >'< with >ft.<:

```
'Super Crew 5 1/2ft. Bed 4WD'
```

the query works.  But it will not be practical to edit all fields containing single quotes each time a new database is delivered.

I have looked at *parametrization*, but that will not work as the field would still require the single quote embedded in the field be escaped with another single quote:

SET @Value = 'Super Crew 5 1/2'' Bed 4WD'

Again, this requires editing, which is not an option for us.

Since I cannot *escape* a single quote embedded in a provided field, is there a way I can package it into a query string so that it will not be rejected as an illegal query?

***EDIT*** (to show function problem exists in)

Note, in the code below, `char *title` is obtained in a previous call, it contains the column data just as it is stored in the database. >>>Super Crew 5 1/2' Bed 4WD<<<

```
int AMSDB_API ams_get_tid_from_title(char *title, int *titleId)
{
    int index, status, iStatus, tid;
    char query[500];

    sprintf (query, "SELECT TitleIndex.TitleId FROM TitleIndex WHERE TitleIndex.Title=\'%s\'", title);
    hstmt = DBActivateSQL(hAmsIndex, query);

    //numberRecords = DBNumberOfRecords(hstmt); 

    status = DBBindColInt (hstmt, 1, &tid, &iStatus);
    DBFetchNext(hstmt);
    DBDeactivateSQL(hstmt);
    *titleId = tid;

    return status;
}
```

Comment: `WHERE TitleIndex.Title='Super Crew 5 1/2\' Bed 4WD'`. You need to escape the `'` (`\'`).

Comment: Parametrization is the correct solution and it will work if you do it correctly. Therefore, you need to show us what you have tried (in *code*), and also let us know what DBMS this is (as parametrization varies between platforms).

Comment: @Ben - Requires editing.  Read the reasons I gave for not being able to do that.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - Can you tell me specifically what part is missing.  The line _...WHERE TitleIndex.Title='Super Crew 5 1/2' Bed 4WD'_ is really the crux of the problem.  I read that field from column data in the database in a prior call, into a string variable, then attempt to use it in another query.  Tell me what part of my code you would like to see, and I will edit my post.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - Would Parametrization not require that at some point I edit the problem piece of column data before placing it into parameters?

Comment: Use parametrisation. You provide the query, with placeholders for where the values go, and the DBM does the rest, escaping and quoting where necessary.

Comment: Most probably you have to use some function before the insert command.  Something to sanitize your input string. Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11416125/escaping-unwanted-characters-mainly-single-quotes-replace-function-and-implem

Comment: @RBarryYoung _ will edit my post, but as I said, I have considered parametrization, but do not yet understand how it will apply in  my situation.  Pls, one minute, I will add more to post.

Comment: And no, proper parametrization would *only* require escaping data if it is hard-coded in your program somewhere. Since this is variable data coming from a "delivered database", there is so far no reason why that should ever happen. Read it from the DB as a variable, then provide it to your queries as a parameter variable and *NOT* as text that you are trying to inject into your SQL commands.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - _Read it from the DB as a variable, then provide it to your queries as a parameter variable and NOT as text that you are trying to inject into your SQL commands_. See my edit, is this _not_ doing what you suggested already?  If not, Can you provide a small example of how to do that.  If being in a _parameter_ will cause it to be processed differently than as a concatenated string, I will use it.

Comment: WHERE TitleIndex.Title='Super Crew 5 1/2'' Bed 4WD'

To escape a single quote in SQL, it needs another single quote in front of it. https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=sql%20single%20quote

Comment: @RBarryYoung - thanks for the edit, but I am not using VBA.  NI LabWindows/CVI (an ANSI C environment with extended libraries, including query)

Comment: @gnomed - editing data from existing field is not an option.  Single quote is included in that field already.

Comment: I am not asking you to edit data in a field. You have the title as a char* in your function. Scrub the string and be done with it. How is this an issue?

Comment: VBA is included with MS-Access.

Comment: @R.. - why did you edit the post to eliminate the C tag.  Does it not matter that I am using C?

Comment: @gnomed - I think I see what you are saying, modify the string, using standard C string techniques, before including it in the query by inserting an additional single quote. Actually, this is probably about the best suggestion I have seen.  If you care to put it into a simple answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @ryyker precisely what I was suggesting. Answer added, but no pressure.

Comment: @ryyker: The question came up under the C tag for me, and nothing in the content seemed to pertain to C or be something that a person following the C tag would have any reason to have the knowledge to answer. Now that you've added the C code to the question, I think it's appropriate to have the C tag, and the issue is just a simple SQL injection problem (don't use `%s` with literals to make SQL queries).

Comment: @R.. - Thanks.  Sorry for the confusion, my mistake.  (I thought the C code was there before the tag.).  regarding your comment _don't use %s with literals to make SQL queries_ is precisely my problem.  The question remains, how then shall I solve the problem?  From what I have read using parametrized methods are still an issue.  The only direction I see is to modify the string as gnomed has suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know, to use a single quote within a query string, it needs to be escaped with another single quote.

As the simplest/fastest to implement solution, you can "escape" the title string in your C function. You have a reference to the search string (title) as a `char *` with this string reference you can find any single quotes and escape them with another single quote. Then use this modified string in your query.

Sorry I am not providing code, C is not my strong point.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is my only path. Admittedly, I am not seasoned with SQL syntax, or techniques. But I am capable of modifying a C string to remove any offending embedded syntax before using it in a query.   Regarding _C is not my strong point_, We are even, SQL syntax/technique is not mine.    Thanks again. –

Answer (score 0):

OK, I see that this is MS-Access and yes, Access does make it inordinately hard to do proper SQL parameterization.  The Microsoft doc does explain it here though: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd671279(v=office.12).aspx

In short what you have to do is to put your variable value into a Global or Module level variable.

```
Public pstrParameter1 As String
```

Then you have to write a publicly visible VBA function that will return that global/module variable's value.

```
Public Function Parmeter1Value() As String
    Parmeter1Value = pstrParmeter1
End Function
```

Finally, your Access SQL query must call that function to supply the variable value to SQL.

```
...WHERE TitleIndex.Title=Parameter1Value()
```

Kludgy, but thats MS-Acces for you.

Comment: In my earlier comments, I responded to the RDBMs? question with _Microsoft Access, and I am using an implementation of database calls from National Instruments, LabWindows/CVI (an ANSI C environment with extended libraries, including query)_. VBA will not work for me. I think I am limited to using C functions to modify the string variable I get on a previous query, to either change the ' to a ft. symbol, or exclude it with an additional ' before using it on any subsequent queries. Thanks for your help.