# Where with And Clause SQL, Access-VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

[image: Run time Error message]

Hi Everyone, Another Installment of WTF am I missing?
When I run this code I get a missing operator run-time Error, see attached photo.

I can't seem to figure it out. This string is used to open a recordset that will populate a form.

```
Private Sub BtnUseSelection_Click()

Dim CompSQL As String

CompSQL = "SELECT T1Company.LegalName, T2AddressType.AddressType, T1Addresses.City" & _
                    " FROM T2AddressType INNER JOIN (T1Addresses INNER JOIN (T1Company INNER JOIN T3Company_Addresses ON T1Company.CompanyID = T3Company_Addresses.CompanyID) ON T1Addresses.AddressID = T3Company_Addresses.AddressID)" & _
                    " ON T2AddressType.AddressTypeID = T1Addresses.AddressType" & _
                    " WHERE T1Company.LegalName = " & Me.LstboxCompanies.Column(0) & " And T2AddressType.AddressType = " & Me.LstboxCompanies.Column(1) & " And T1Addresses.City = " & Me.LstboxCompanies.Column(2)

Set db = CurrentDb

Set RSCompany = db.OpenRecordset(CompSQL, dbOpenSnapshot, dbSeeChanges)
```

Not quite sure what I am missing, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you've missed the ' ' around your string literals.

instead of

```
... WHERE T1Company.LegalName = " & Me.LstboxCompanies.Column(0) & " ...
```

use:

```
... WHERE T1Company.LegalName = '" & Me.LstboxCompanies.Column(0) & "' ...
```

You also need to escape your strings to avoid corruption of the command (or sql injections). Look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11416125/escaping-unwanted-characters-mainly-single-quotes-replace-function-and-implem) for some info.

Answer (score 2):

Consider [parameterizing query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193967.aspx) to avoid any need for quote enclosure or string concatenation.

**SQL**  *(save below as a saved Access query, more efficient than VBA string query as database engine saves best execution plan)*

```sql
PARAMETERS [LegalNameParam] Text(255), [AddressTypeParam] Text(255),
           [CityParam] Text(255);
SELECT T1Company.LegalName, T2AddressType.AddressType, T1Addresses.City
FROM T2AddressType
INNER JOIN (T1Addresses INNER JOIN (T1Company
            INNER JOIN T3Company_Addresses
             ON T1Company.CompanyID = T3Company_Addresses.CompanyID)
  ON T1Addresses.AddressID = T3Company_Addresses.AddressID)
  ON T2AddressType.AddressTypeID = T1Addresses.AddressType
WHERE T1Company.LegalName = [LegalNameParam]
 AND T2AddressType.AddressType = [AddressTypeParam]
 AND T1Addresses.City = [CityParam]
```

**VBA** *(call the above query and bind values to named parameters)*

```vb
Dim db As Database, RSCompany As Recordset, qdef As QueryDef
Dim CompSQL As String

Set db = CurrentDb    
Set qdef = db.QueryDefs("myStoredQuery")

qdef!LegalNameParam = Me.LstboxCompanies.Column(0)
qdef!AddressTypeParam = Me.LstboxCompanies.Column(1)
qdef!CityParam = Me.LstboxCompanies.Column(2)

Set RSCompany = qdef.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot, dbSeeChanges)
```

Comment: I've never seen that before I will have to research that more.... would the parameters go  in coding, in their own function/sub or in the same sub?

Comment: Run exactly as I advised, saving SQL as a saved query and running VBA as posted. `PARAMETERS` clause is valid in the Access SQL dialect. Notice the named params in sql query are being assigned values in VBA during runtime. Did you run into any issues?

Comment: Just as a FYI , a snapshot recordset isn't update-able, so no need for the dbSeeChanges.